# Appending HAML code with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, events

Trying to replace a link that takes the user to a separate form page with a link that simply causes the form to slide out of the current page. I know this may be a naive approach, but can something like this work:

```
$("#test-append").click(function() {
      $(this).append('= escape_javascript( render "data_sources/cidne_new.html.haml")');
  })
```

Where I just append a rendering of the form page to the link. I'm pretty sure this won't work, and I have to use Ajax to fetch the form, but I don't know. Maybe the above approach does work, I'm just doing it wrong. Right now this just appends the text of the string directly onto the link, which is definitely not what I'm seeking.

So, given the above situation, can I ever format that function to build the form directly on the page, or am I going down the wrong path?

Comment: Why don't you render a partial (i.e. form) already on the page and just show/hide using the link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe and assign the url of your page on javascript event then the contents will be loaded dynamically.

```
$("#test-append").click(function() {
      $('#iframeId').attr('src', 'urlYouHave')
});
```